# $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ s.t. $f(x) = 1$ for $x\in\Bbb Q$ and $f(x) = 0$ for $x\notin \Bbb Q$ is discontinuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ s.t. $f(x) = 1$ for $x\in\Bbb Q$ and $f(x) = 0$ for $x\notin \Bbb Q$ is discontinuous.

So the function above is obviously discontinuous, and I am looking to prove the same. One way that comes to mind is constructing a sequence $x_n\to x$ s.t. $f(x_n)\not\to f(x)$.

How about $$x_n = 2  - \frac{\sqrt 2}{n}$$
$x_n$ is irrational for every $n$, but $x_n\to 2\in \Bbb Q$. In other words, $f(x_n) = 0$ for all $n$, but $f(x) = 1$. This suffices, right?

---

Also, I have trouble understanding a proof of the same result in Carothers' Real Analysis:

> **(Example $5.2$)** $f^{-1}(B(1,1/3)) = \mathbb Q$ and $f^{-1}(B(0,1/3)) = \mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$. Thus, $f$ cannot be continuous at any point of $\mathbb R$ since $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$ do not contain intervals.

$B(x,r)$ is the open ball of radius $r$ centered at $x$. I don't see how $f^{-1}(B(1,1/3)) = \mathbb Q$ and $f^{-1}(B(0,1/3)) = \mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$ come about, and from there the rest of the argument.

Thank you!

Comment: Your argument is correct. What is used in the other argument is the fact that if $f$ is continuous, then the preimage of any open subset by $f$ must be open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the last question:

The inverse of continuous function transforms open sets into open sets. $B(1,1/3)$ is an open set but $f^{-1}(B(1,1/3))=\Bbb Q$ cannot be open since it does not contain any interval (so, in particular, it can not contain a neighborhood of any point).

The same occurs for $f^{-1}(B(0,1/3))=\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$.

---

For the first one the argument is correct.

You can also do it in the opposite way: take your favourite irrational number say $\pi$. Antd take $(x_n)$ to be the next sequence: $$\{3,\, 3.1,\, 3.14,\, 3.141,\, 3.1415,\, 3.14159,\,\ldots\}$$
It is clear that $x_n\in\Bbb Q$ so $f(x_n)=1$ but $x_n\to\pi$ and $f(\pi)=0$-